# why use not not !! for boolean value in MS AJAX?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax

From MS AJAX source code,

```
Type.isClass = function Type$isClass(type) {
/// <summary locid="M:J#Type.isClass" />
/// <param name="type" mayBeNull="true"></param>
/// <returns type="Boolean"></returns>
var e = Function._validateParams(arguments, [
    {name: "type", mayBeNull: true}
]);
if (e) throw e;
if ((typeof(type) === 'undefined') || (type === null)) return false;
return !!type.__class;
```

}

Please look at the last line of code, why use !! instead of just return type.__class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The author must not have thought `type.__class` was guaranteed to be a boolean value. Since you can pass any object to `Type.isClass()`:

```
Type.isClass(3);
Type.isClass({});
Type.isClass(AnActualClassFunction);
```

...there's really no guarantee that `type.__class` will have a boolean value.

Of course, parameters that aren't ASP.NET AJAX "classes" generally won't have a `__class` property - so if the routine simply returned `type.__class`, the possible return values would be `true`, `false`, and `undefined`. This is undesirable for a routine intended to return a boolean.

`!!type.__class` just guarantees that a boolean value (`true` or `false`) is returned (`undefined` will be converted to `false`).

Comment: wow - you edited that a lot.  uh, thanks. (I understand Javascript pretty well.  ASP.NET, not so much)

Comment: Your answer piqued my curiosity - i'm not a heavy ASP.NET AJAX user either, but figured there must be a likely scenario where __class wouldn't have a boolean value already. Hope you don't mind the additions!

Comment: So how does this work? I don't get rep points for this because it's been edited?

Comment: You should - perhaps you've hit your rep limit (200pts) for today?

Comment: oh wow, I think maybe I have. 

that's what I get for late-night SOing I guess.

Comment: Heh, yeah... The reset time is 0:00GMT, which kinda punishes after-work SOing by those of us in the US.

Comment: Do you  know if these rep points will carry over and be rewarded tomorrow?  Or are the lost forever?  Couldn't figure it out from the faqs

Comment: They're effectively gone. When you hit the limit, it's a good time to take a break from answering questions and do something else (edit/re-tag other posts, actual work ;-))

Answer (score 0):

Guaranteed safe boolean conversion.

Comment: Is it any different than: return Boolean(type.__class) in terms of safety?

Comment: @Ates Goral: The results should be exactly the same - !! is merely more concise.

Comment: I'm told that !! is more efficient in C, so perhaps it is in JS too, otherwise yes just conciseness

Answer (score 0):

So basically there is no difference between !!val and Boolean(val)

```
var val; // val is undefined
alert(!!val); // display false
alert(Boolean(val)); // display false as well
```

Comment: That is correct. The same rules are used to coerce val to a boolean in both cases. !! is familiar to C++ users, and somewhat more concise, hence its popularity. Note that "new Boolean(val)" produces a completely different result, which may also help account for a reluctance to use Boolean(val).